# Double counting proof: The number of streets that direct to or away from a place $o$ is $s(o)$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

On a map there are $n$ places, that are connected with streets. Every street connects exactly $2$ places. The number of streets that direct to or away from a place $o$ is $s(o)$.

How can one find out the number of streets via Double counting?

Here's what I thought of:

We define the following:
$n$ places, $m$ streets, $O$ is the set of places and $M$ the set of streets.

$$(o,m) \Leftrightarrow m \text{ is on o}  $$

$$s(o*) = \text{Number of streets at one place} = 2$$
$$r(m*) = \text{Number of places at one street} = 2$$

$$\sum_{o* \in O } s(o*) = n \cdot s(o) = n s(o)$$
$$\sum_{m* \in M } r(m*) = m \cdot 2 = 2m$$

$\Rightarrow 2m = n s(o)$

$\Rightarrow m = \frac{ns(o)}{2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: I assume $s(0)$ is the number of streets connected specifically to place $o$ ... and that for different $o$'s you can have different values for $s(o)$. So, you just need to sum the different $s(0)$'s and divide by $2$, rather than assume that $s(o)$ is the same value for all places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $s(0)$ is the number of streets connected specifically to place $o$ ... and that for different $o$'s you can have different values for $s(o)$. So, you just need to sum the different $s(0)$'s and divide by $2$, rather than assume that $s(o)$ is the same value for all places. Thus, you get:

$$m = \frac{\sum_{o \in O} s(o)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you like graph theory, which this question suggests you might, use a handshaking approach as the indegree + outdegree = degree of a vertex where we are double counting streets.

Or just at each place count all streets add it up and divide by two.